# Building a table in jQuery doesn't add element to all cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The table is being populated using information stored in a database. The JavaScript is linked with MVC. Below is the code for populating the table:

```
function populatePageTable(tableList, status) {
clearPageTable();
var recent = $('#static-pages');

$.each(tableList, function (index, entry) {
    recent.append($('<tr>')
            .append($('<td>').text(entry.spId))
            .append($('<td>').text(entry.spTitle))
            .append($('<td>').text(entry.spBody))
            .append($('<td>').text(entry.spPath))
            .append($('<td>').append(btnEdit))
            .append($('<td>').append(btnRemove)
                    .attr({
                        'onClick': 'deletePage(' + entry.spId + ')'
                    })));
});}
```

[The webpage displays this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tqIf.png)

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Seems that, the code is Working

Comment: Are edit and delete buttons always visible or only on hover?

Comment: I got it to work. If you replace btnEdit and btnRemove with their respective button links (i.e. `'<a href="/edit-static-page/"' + entry.spPath + '><button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></a>'` it'll work.

Comment: My guess would be that `btnEdit` and `btnRemove` were individual JQuery objects, so when you appended them to each `td`, they were removed from the previous one (since they can only have one parent). This explains why replacing them with the text needed to create those buttons made it work.